# Can't loading Header,Footer component in Lazy loading component (Angular 5)

Tags: angular

In my angular 5 project i have `HeaderComponent`,`FooterComponent` and some lazy loading modules there.

In app.modules.ts

```
 declarations: [....
HeaderComponent,FooterComponent.....]
```

In header.component.ts

```
....
 @Component({
      selector: 'ls-header',
      templateUrl: './header.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
    })
@Input() public showHome: string = "N";
....
```

In lazyLoad.component.ts

```
......
    <ls-header [showHome]="'Y'" [showLogout]="'Y'" ></ls-header>
......
```

I am trying to access the url (Lazy loading) and i am getting

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'showHome' since it isn't a known property of 'header'.
```

Comment: Your `header` component needs an `@Input() showHome` in the component.

Comment: That is already there  @Input() showHome: string = "N";

Comment: Show me the `HeaderComponent`, especially @Component annotation code

Comment: EDITED.Kindly check now  @Antoniossss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, your selector is `selector: 'ls-header',`  not `header` and this is what you should use in your markup

```
  <ls-header [showHome]="'Y'" [showLogout]="'Y'" ></ls-header>
```

Comment: Sorry before also some like this only. I am just give you example of header instead of ls header. Any help highly appreciated

Comment: @VikramR I don't understand what you do mean:(

Answer (score 0):

Where you call the header component you should have something like this:

```
<ls-header [showHome]="inputValue"></ls-header>
```

Comment: Are you sure the component's name is  **<header>** and not _<app-header>_ by default? Maybe the compiler misinterpret the tag **<header>** from the component _<header>_

Comment: EDITED.Kindly check now

Comment: EDITED. check my answer now

Comment: Sorry before also some like this only. I am just give you example of header instead of ls header. Any help highly appreciated

Comment: Sorry I don't undestand what you mean. Can you explain it better?